# typeORM using spread operator when updating values in an entity

Tags: javascript, typescript, typeorm

I'm learning to build a backend using TypeORM and Typescript and just wanted to ask why spread operators won't work when updating a entity.

Say I have a user that has a bunch of properties:

- name
- email
- password

And in the frontend I have a form that allows me to update any one of these values.

How can I use one route to update one of all of these value?

I'm trying to do this and it is telling me that update values are undefined:

```
@PUT 
@Path("/:email")
async updateUser(@PathParm("email") email: string, data: User):Promise<object> {
  try {
    const user = await getRepository(User)
      .createQueryBuilder()
      .update(User)
      .set({ ...data }) // the issue
      .where('email = :email', { email })
      .execute()
   return user
 catch(e) {
   return e
 }
```

I would have though a spread operator would work fine in this scenario?

Or do I have to be verbose and write out each property of the User entity to set?

Comment: I just tried with POST MAN using the 'raw' data and it worked...

Comment: What http framework are you using? What exactly is `data`? Does it have own enumerable properties?

Comment: So, I ended up making progress on this. I was sending `form-data` with POSTMAN, but when I switched to `x-www-form-urlencoded` it worked just fine. I need a parser for form-data if I use that